# how to find total count of nulls present in a DataFrame using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a command in Scala to find the sum of nulls in all the columns present in a DataFrame.

In python I can get it using the command:
`Df.isnull().sum()`

Can you let me know the scala command for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no spark function to do that but you can count the number of null values in each column and then compute the sum of all these values.

Here is sample data:

```scala
val df = spark.range(5).select(
    when('id % 2 === 0, 'id) as "mod2",
    when('id %3 === 0, 'id) as "mod3"
)
df.show
+----+----+
|mod2|mod3|
+----+----+
|   0|   0|
|null|null|
|   2|null|
|null|   3|
|   4|null|
+----+----+
```

And here is a solution:

```
val result = df.select( 
    df.columns
      // null count per column
      .map(c => sum(isnull(col(c)) cast "int"))
      // computing the sum
      .reduce(_+_) as "total_nulls"
)
result.show
+-----------+
|total_nulls|
+-----------+
|          5|
+-----------+
```

NB: use `result.head.getAs[Long](0)` to get the total out of the `result` dataframe.